# Show textarea content with CKEditor in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, ckeditor, strip-tags

I use CKEditor in my application for edit text

when i store my text in data base it will save with tags like this :

```
<p>Hello world</p><p>how are you ?</p>
```

and in my blade when i want to display this text, it will show with tags so i use `strip_tags` :

```
<div id="detail_textarea">
     {{ strip_tags($letter->text) }}
</div>
```

but when i look at the page, styles does not work and all the text are sticky like this :

```
Hello worldhow are you ?
```

in this case seems to `<br>` or `<p>` does not work correctly.

what can i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}`

**Update**

```
<div id="detail_textarea">
     {!! $letter->text !!}
</div>
```

Comment: oh no sry, its working now when i remove strip_tags, thank you <3